# Flask,Jinja : define Variable for Dict Key consisting "dot"

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am working on Jinja template and accessing the keys of a dictionary dump coming from Python code as.
`return render_template('dashboard.html', data=data)`
Few of the keys within dictionary as `"."` for example `{'this_is.key_with.dots':'value of key'}`
Within template I tried using couple of formats i.e.,
`{{ data['this_is.key_with.dots] }}` as well as `{{ data['this_is.key_with.dots']|e }}.
Tried going though link https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/ but couldn't find much in escaping characters in variable.
If someone got idea on this would be helpful to know.

Thanks for the time.

Comment: Can you post your HTML? Also I think if you do something like this ```<p>{{data['this_is.key_with.dots']}}</p>``` it should work!